# How to dispose a StateFullWidget which has AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin?

Tags: flutter

Lets say I have this very simple widget

```
    class Example extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
    }

    class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Example> {
    @override
    bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        super.build(context); // Necessary to call super.build

        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Example'),
        ),
        body: const Center(child: Text(context.watch<TextBloc>().state.text)),
        );
    }
    }
```

The problem here is that this Example widget is in a PageView, so lets say

PageView(children: [Example(), etc, etc])

inside this pageview i want the Example widget to be kept alive since this is a form.

It works perfectly, state is kept alive while i switch pages in the pageview.

the problem comes when i leave the pageview. When flutter disposes of the pageview it seems that the Example() page is kept alive and it throws an error since it is still trying to access the context that was distroyed. The TextBloc was only accessible inside the PageView and it is probably related to that, the Example() tries to access a bloc that no longer exists.

I would like to destroy Example() when user leaves the pageview but all i see is updateKeepAlive() but I have no idea how to implement it